# Result query doesnt has the entire result at first

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

im using oracle 11g R2,the result of this query:

```
SELECT u.object_name,u.object_type,t.owner,DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(object_type, object_name)
FROM user_objects u
inner join all_tables t
on u.object_name = t.table_name;
```

Just show me the first 50 rows , it needs to scroll down the query result tab to get the other results and query looks like it is working when i scrolled.

How can i fix it??

Comment: Its probably the query tool being slow to draw the screen. Try using a different query tool like TOAD or PL/SQL developer.

Comment: I see the same as the O.P. any time I use Oracle SQL Developer. There may be an option in the settings to increase the return set size. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Developer, you can change the fetch size here:

> Tools->Preferences->Database->Advanced

The first option is "Sql Array Fetch Size (Max 500).  The default is 50.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the problem is or what a fix would look like.

The client application that you are using to run the query decides how many rows to fetch before displaying the data to you and whether to continue fetching data or to wait for you to request more rows.  You don't say which client application you are using so it is hard to tell you whether or how to configure your particular client to behave differently.  If you are using SQL Developer, there are settings that control how many rows to fetch so you can adjust the default from 50.  Other GUIs likely have similar settings.

Alternately, you could use a client application like SQL*Plus whose default behavior is to fetch all the rows without trying to page through the results for a human.

Comment: you mean like set the arraysize of sql*plus?

Comment: @Arquitecto - `arraysize` controls the number of rows that SQL*Plus fetches with every network round-trip.  It does not control whether SQL*Plus pauses to wait for human input periodically.  By default, SQL*Plus will fetch all the data and write it to the console without waiting for human input which appears to be your desired behavior.